# How to trace method call in class instance in ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to explain to my colleague about how ruby search for method definition.

So i made two classes

```rb
class Pet
 def food
   "food"
 end
end

class Cat < Pet
  def sound
   "meow"
  end
end

cat = Cat.new
cat.sound
cat.food
cat.inspect
```

How can i get traceback of method calls i did `cat.sound`, `cat.food`, `cat.inspect` so then i can prove that ruby found the method in correct class?
(`sound` at `Cat`, `food` at `Pet`, and `inspect` at `Object`)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ruby has reflection which helps you find out where these methods are defined, for example:

```
cat = Cat.new
cat.method(:sound)
=> #<Method: Cat#sound() (irb):8>
cat.method(:food)
=> #<Method: Cat(Pet)#food() (irb):2>
```

This is like `inspect` but for defined methods.